# Undefined property: Google_Http_Request::$id when trying to insert file into Drive

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I'm trying to insert a user-submitted file into a specific folder named after the user, using [yannisg's Google Uploader](https://github.com/yannisg/Google-Drive-Uploader-PHP/blob/master/gdrive_upload.php) as base and a modified version of Google Drive example. The folder is created during the upload process. But I'm getting the above error about undefined id. Then it uploads the file into Drive's root folder. I'm using the [v1-master](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/tree/v1-master) of the PHP client.

```
function upload(){
    $client = $this->client;
    $service = $this->service; //$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

    //Create folder
    $folder = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
        'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'));
    $folder->setTitle($this->ownerName); //applicant's name
    $folderData = $service->files->insert($folder, array(
        'fields' => 'id'));

    //create file
    $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
    $file->title = $this->fileName;
    $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

    $fileRequest = $this->fileRequest;
    $mimeType = $this->mimeType;

    //Set parent id
    $parent = new Google_Service_Drive_ParentReference();
    $parent->setId($folderData->id);
    $file->setParents(array($parent));

    $request = $service->files->insert($file);

    //The rest of the script...
}
```

I think the problem lies here

```
$parent->setId($folderData->id);
```

Here's the same portion from the modified example script that works nicely. I would've have used this but I can't seem to properly integrate it into another script I need to run. And yannisg's have the refresh token taken care of.

```
//Create folder   
$folder = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
    'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'));
$folder->setTitle($_FILES["uploaded"]["name"]); //applicant's name
$folderData = $service->files->insert($folder, array(
    'fields' => 'id'));

var_dump($folderData);

//Create file
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$file->title = $_FILES["uploaded"]["name"];
$chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

//Set parent id
$parent = new Google_Service_Drive_ParentReference(); //previously Google_ParentReference
$parent->setId($folderData->id);
$file->setParents(array($parent));
```

Var dumping the second script gives me object(Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile) while the first gave object(Google_Http_Request). Is it because the first one is in a class?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the `$service` is still derived from the original Google Drive API, there's no `insert` method. The appropriate API for creating a file is [`create`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/create). The response object will be of the [Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource) resource that contains the `id` which you can use to set the `$parent->setId`

Comment: @adjuremods I'm using the v1-master version of the php client, and there's no `create` method. But `insert` is indeed [there](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert). Sorry I missed this information. Will edit to reflect this.

Comment: I'm assuming the [API Client for PHP](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/get_started) won't support older versions of the REST API, as the objects in the library seems to support resources for v3. You can look at [this repo](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/tree/v1-master) which seems to cater to older versions of the Drive API. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. It was related to deferring. In yannisg's script,

```
$client->setDefer(true);
```

is declared in an earlier function, which means the statement for creating the folder are executed together with the file. No wonder it couldn't grab the parents id. After moving it below the folder insertion part, everything works properly once again.

```
//folder insertion    

$client->setDefer(true);
$request = $service->files->insert($file); //file insertion
```